# Using easeOutQuart in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add `easeOutQuart` into my script when the panel slides in and out on toggle.

```
$("#toggle").click(function() {
if ($('#panel').css('display') == 'block') {
    var height = '-=' + $('#panel').height();
} else {
    var height = '+=' + $('#panel').height();
}
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow", "easeOutQuart");
$(".project_wrap").animate({
    bottom: height
}, "slow", "easeOutQuart")
});
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to load jQuery UI to have access to those easings.

http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Comment: Ah stupid me. I used assumed these were built into the normal jQuery build.